# What are the modules to use Google Maps with other data in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, google-maps

Let's say I want to create maps of crime, education, traffic or etc on a street or a city. What are the modules I need to learn or the best ones?

For some data, I will be using excell like documents where I will have street names or building numbers unlinked to Google Maps directly and will be combined later through codes. For some, I want to obtain data directly from Google Maps, such as names of the stores or street numbers. I'm a beginner and a sociologist and this is the main reason I want to learn programming. Maybe painting on a map picture can be a lot easier but on the long term my aim is using Google Maps since it can obtain data by itself. Thanks in advance.

I'm a beginner, need a long shot plan and an advice. I watched some numpy and pandas videos and they seem ok and doable so far.

Answer (score 0):

There are several Python modules that can be used to work with Google Maps data. Some of the most popular ones include:

**Google Maps API:** This is the official API for working with Google Maps data. It allows you to access a wide range of data, including street maps, satellite imagery, and places of interest. You can use the API to search for addresses, get directions, and even create custom maps.

**gmaps:** This is a Python wrapper for the Google Maps API. It makes it easy to work with the API by providing a simple, Pythonic interface. It also includes support for several popular Python libraries, such as Pandas and Numpy.

**folium:** This is a library for creating leaflet maps in Python. It allows you to create interactive maps, add markers and other data, and customize the appearance of your maps.

**geopandas:** This library allows you to work with geospatial data in Python. It is built on top of the popular Pandas library and includes support for working with shapefiles, geojson, and more.

**geopy:** This is a Python library for working with geocoding and distance calculations. It can be used to convert addresses to latitude and longitude coordinates, as well as to perform distance calculations between two points.

In general, it's recommended to start with Google Maps API and gmaps and folium, you can also use geopandas and geopy later when you need more advanced functionalities. Try to start with simple examples and gradually increase the complexity of your projects.